# Clase muestra valores que no corresponden al select

Tags: php

Estoy usando PHP / MySQL y en una clase tengo una función que debe buscar dos valores máximos en una sola línea y tengo este código:

```
$sql = "SELECT max(id) as id, max(lote) as lote FROM sc_operac limit 1";
$bd = new ConexionDB();
$stmt = $bd->query($sql);
$row = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$registroVO = new OperacionesVO();
$registroVO->set_id( $row );
$registroVO->set_lote( $row );
print_r($registroVO);
return $registroVO;
```

Pero el ***print_r*** muestra que tanto **set_id** y **set_lote** tienen el mismo valor del primero (**set_id**), por qué ocurre esto si son dos valores diferentes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que `fetchColumn()` devuelve el primer dato sólo. por lo que para acceder al segundo dato tienes que utilizar `fetchColumn(1)`.

```
$sql = "SELECT max(id) as id, max(lote) as lote FROM sc_operac limit 1";
$bd = new ConexionDB();
$stmt = $bd->query($sql);
$row = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$row2 = $stmt->fetchColumn(1);
$registroVO = new OperacionesVO();
$registroVO->set_id( $row );
$registroVO->set_lote( $row2 );
print_r($registroVO);
return $registroVO;
```

Comment: Significa que si tengo muchos campos en el select de ese registro debo agregar otro fetchColumn(n) por cada campo?

Comment: Si, aunque tienes otras formas de obtener los datos